# Removing certain elements from a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have this list as an example:

```
L1 = {{1, 7, 23, 31, 19}, {1, 19, 17, 35, 9}, {1, 9, 25, 37, 21}, {1, 21, 15, 33, 7}, {2, 8, 24, 34, 20}, {2, 20, 18, 38, 10}, {2, 10, 26, 36, 22}, {2, 22, 16, 32, 8}, {3, 11, 28, 34, 24}, {3, 24, 8, 32, 12}, {3, 12, 27, 31, 23}, {3, 23, 7, 33, 11}, {4, 13, 30, 36, 26}, {4, 26, 10, 38, 14}, {4, 14, 29, 37, 25}, {4, 25, 9, 35, 13}, {5, 16, 22, 36, 30}, {5, 30, 13, 35, 17}, {5, 17, 19, 31, 27}, {5, 27, 12, 32, 16}, {6, 15, 21, 37, 29}, {6, 29, 14, 38, 18}, {6, 18, 20, 34, 28}, {6, 28, 11, 33, 15}}
```

I want to remove all elements {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} from this list to give the following list as an output:

```
L2 = {{7, 23, 31, 19}, {19, 17, 35, 9}, {9, 25, 37, 21}, {21, 15, 33, 7}, {8, 24, 34, 20}, {20, 18, 38, 10}, {10, 26, 36,22}, {22, 16, 32, 8}, {11, 28, 34, 24}, {24, 8, 32, 12}, {12, 27, 31, 23}, {23, 7, 33, 11}, {13, 30, 36, 26}, {26, 10, 38, 14}, {14, 29, 37, 25}, {25, 9, 35, 13}, {16, 22, 36, 30}, {30, 13, 35, 17}, {17, 19, 31, 27}, {27, 12, 32, 16}, {15, 21, 37, 29}, {29, 14, 38, 18}, {18, 20, 34, 28}, {28, 11, 33, 15}}
```

In this case each time the first element of a of the list {a,b,c,d,e} is removed, however this might not always be the case for other examples.

My question is what is the best way to do this. I was thinking of two for-loops, but I am sure there is a nicer way to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DeleteCases[L1, Alternatives @@ Range@6, {2}]
```

Similar to @bmf but using the levelspec argument instead of mapping.

Comment: I think this is the fastest solution

Comment: Thank you @lericr! This works perfectly

Answer (score 6):

> I was thinking of two for-loops,

That would probably be the Fortran or C way. In Mathematica there is no need to do this. You just need to find the builtin function instead and use that.

There are at least 10 ways to do this in Mathematica. One way could be

```
L1 = {{1, 7, 23, 31, 19}, {1, 19, 17, 35, 9}, {1, 9, 25, 37, 21}, {1, 
   21, 15, 33, 7}, {2, 8, 24, 34, 20}, {2, 20, 18, 38, 10}, {2, 10, 
   26, 36, 22}, {2, 22, 16, 32, 8}, {3, 11, 28, 34, 24}, {3, 24, 8, 
   32, 12}, {3, 12, 27, 31, 23}, {3, 23, 7, 33, 11}, {4, 13, 30, 36, 
   26}, {4, 26, 10, 38, 14}, {4, 14, 29, 37, 25}, {4, 25, 9, 35, 
   13}, {5, 16, 22, 36, 30}, {5, 30, 13, 35, 17}, {5, 17, 19, 31, 
   27}, {5, 27, 12, 32, 16}, {6, 15, 21, 37, 29}, {6, 29, 14, 38, 
   18}, {6, 18, 20, 34, 28}, {6, 28, 11, 33, 15}}

del={1,2,3,4,5,6}
Map[DeleteElements[#,del]&,L1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

see https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteElements.html

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) such elements with [`Nothing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html), which gets removed from lists.

```
L1 = {{1, 7, 23, 31, 19}, {1, 19, 17, 35, 9}, {1, 9, 25, 37, 21}, {1, 
    21, 15, 33, 7}, {2, 8, 24, 34, 20}, {2, 20, 18, 38, 10}, {2, 10, 
    26, 36, 22}, {2, 22, 16, 32, 8}, {3, 11, 28, 34, 24}, {3, 24, 8, 
    32, 12}, {3, 12, 27, 31, 23}, {3, 23, 7, 33, 11}, {4, 13, 30, 36, 
    26}, {4, 26, 10, 38, 14}, {4, 14, 29, 37, 25}, {4, 25, 9, 35, 
    13}, {5, 16, 22, 36, 30}, {5, 30, 13, 35, 17}, {5, 17, 19, 31, 
    27}, {5, 27, 12, 32, 16}, {6, 15, 21, 37, 29}, {6, 29, 14, 38, 
    18}, {6, 18, 20, 34, 28}, {6, 28, 11, 33, 15}};
L2 = {{7, 23, 31, 19}, {19, 17, 35, 9}, {9, 25, 37, 21}, {21, 15, 33, 
    7}, {8, 24, 34, 20}, {20, 18, 38, 10}, {10, 26, 36, 22}, {22, 16, 
    32, 8}, {11, 28, 34, 24}, {24, 8, 32, 12}, {12, 27, 31, 23}, {23, 
    7, 33, 11}, {13, 30, 36, 26}, {26, 10, 38, 14}, {14, 29, 37, 
    25}, {25, 9, 35, 13}, {16, 22, 36, 30}, {30, 13, 35, 17}, {17, 19,
     31, 27}, {27, 12, 32, 16}, {15, 21, 37, 29}, {29, 14, 38, 
    18}, {18, 20, 34, 28}, {28, 11, 33, 15}};
L3 = L1 /. Alternatives @@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} -> Nothing
L4 = L1 /. 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 -> Nothing (* equivalent *)
L2 == L3 == L4
```

[image: Mathematica output]

Comment: (+1) from me. Just a comment: this `L1 /. Thread[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} -> Nothing]` is more straightforward and shorter I think

Answer (score 5):

Just joining the party hoping that the following

```
DeleteCases[1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6] /@ L1;
```

counts as a distinct enough solution.

The check

```
LinearAlgebra`Private`ZeroArrayQ@Flatten[% - L2]
```

gives `True`.

Edit: there's also this that came to mind

```
Pick[L1, L1, Except[1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6, _Integer]];
LinearAlgebra`Private`ZeroArrayQ@Flatten[% - L2]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Select[! Between[#, {1, 6}] &] /@ L1
```

{{7, 23, 31, 19}, {19, 17, 35, 9}, {9, 25, 37, 21}, {21, 15, 33,
7}, {8, 24, 34, 20}, {20, 18, 38, 10}, {10, 26, 36, 22}, {22, 16,
32, 8}, {11, 28, 34, 24}, {24, 8, 32, 12}, {12, 27, 31, 23}, {23, 7,
33, 11}, {13, 30, 36, 26}, {26, 10, 38, 14}, {14, 29, 37, 25}, {25,
9, 35, 13}, {16, 22, 36, 30}, {30, 13, 35, 17}, {17, 19, 31,
27}, {27, 12, 32, 16}, {15, 21, 37, 29}, {29, 14, 38, 18}, {18, 20,
34, 28}, {28, 11, 33, 15}}

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
L1 = {{1, 7, 23, 31, 19}, {1, 19, 17, 35, 9}, {1, 9, 25, 37, 21}, {1, 
    21, 15, 33, 7}, {2, 8, 24, 34, 20}, {2, 20, 18, 38, 10}, {2, 10, 
    26, 36, 22}, {2, 22, 16, 32, 8}, {3, 11, 28, 34, 24}, {3, 24, 8, 
    32, 12}, {3, 12, 27, 31, 23}, {3, 23, 7, 33, 11}, {4, 13, 30, 36, 
    26}, {4, 26, 10, 38, 14}, {4, 14, 29, 37, 25}, {4, 25, 9, 35, 
    13}, {5, 16, 22, 36, 30}, {5, 30, 13, 35, 17}, {5, 17, 19, 31, 
    27}, {5, 27, 12, 32, 16}, {6, 15, 21, 37, 29}, {6, 29, 14, 38, 
    18}, {6, 18, 20, 34, 28}, {6, 28, 11, 33, 15}};

alt = Alternatives @@ Range[6];
Delete[L1, Position[L1, alt]]
```

or

```
Pick[L1, Map[FreeQ[alt], L1, {2}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select[Not@*Between[{1, 6}]] /@ L1
```

A point-free version of @eldo's solution.

If we can assume that the values are all positive integers, we could do this instead:

```
Select[GreaterThan[6]] /@ L1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `Position` and `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[L1, Position[L1, Alternatives @@ Range[6]] -> Nothing] === L2

(*True*)
```

Or using `Drop` for this particular case:

```
Drop[#, {1}] & /@ L1 === L2

(*True*)
```

Or using `Cases` for this particular case:

```
Cases[L1, x : {___} :> Rest@x] === L2

(*True*)
```

Comment: The `Cases` and `Drop` solutions work in this particular case, but the first solution is compliant with the OP.

Comment: It seems that `Cases` and `DeleteCases` are somehow inverse functions; they are not. In cases such as these, you can easily use `DeleteCases` or `Delete` or `DeleteElement` or `ReplacePart`. If you choose to use `Cases`, you will have to write difficult patterns or re-establish list structure.

Comment: Thanks mate! At this time, I add your suggestions for clarity in my answer :-)